# CountdownTimer and exiting the Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, countdowntimer

I have made a game module in which a user is granted a minute to answer the questions and then an intent is called to show the result ,my problem is when I exit the activity in the middle, it still shows the result for the time completed on the game no matter on what activity I am.

My code for timer is

```
class MyCount extends CountDownTimer{
    public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
    super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {


        Intent finish= new Intent(QuestionScreen.this,ResultScreen.class);
        finish.putExtra("noofques", Integer.toString(totalquestions));
        finish.putExtra("correct", Integer.toString(score));
        startActivity(finish);
        overridePendingTransition( R.anim.slideinleft, R.anim.slideoutleft);
    }
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        if(millisUntilFinished>60000)
        timerview.setText((millisUntilFinished/(1000*60))+1 +" minutes left");
        else
        {
        timerview.setText(millisUntilFinished/1000 +" seconds left");
        }
    }
    }
```

and code for exiting the game in middle is

```
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertbox.setMessage("Do you really want to quit");
        alertbox.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                Intent info = new Intent(QuestionScreen.this,com.preciselabs.mental_skills.MenuScreen.class);
                info.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                finish();
                startActivity(info);
                overridePendingTransition( R.anim.slideinright, R.anim.slideoutright);
                }
        });
        alertbox.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
           }
        });
        alertbox.show();
    return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

any solution to my problem will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Don't use that `onTick` thing and use a `java.util.Timer` to program some action.

Answer (score 0):

use belove code when you exit activity..

```
  mCount.cancel();
  mCount=null;
```

and a boolean in onfinish() for   startActivity(finish);